# Xml parsing using DOM parser , element from element

Tags: xml, parsing, dom, element

How to get element inside a element, also Xml having multiple element with same name

I need Membership Status element, Not MembershipCard Status.

`getElementsByTagName` will get Membership Status but if Membership Status not available it will goes to MembershipCard Status. I don't want that.

i am using getTextContent() to get text from element.

**xml file in raw folder, Android Studio**

```
<Membership>
  <Program>Fun</Program>
  <Status>CANCELLED</Status>
  <MembershipCard>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <Status>VALID</Status>
    <Version>10</Version>
  </MembershipCard>
</Membership>
```

**code -**

String FirstName = "FirstName";

String Surname = "Surname";

String Status = "Status";

String Membership ="Membership";

//missing some codes here........

//reading file from raw folder...

String s = OfflineServiceClient.readRawTextFile(super.AppContext, resourceId);

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(s));
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
```

// ResponseBody is one of the main element i need, all element is inside the ResponseBody element

```
    if (doc != null)
    {
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ResponseBody");
        if (nList.getLength() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = nList.item(i);
                //  (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                Element eElement = (Element) node;

                try
                {
                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName(FirstName).getLength() > 0 )
                    {
                        enrollmentStatus.setFirstName(eElement.getElementsByTagName(FirstName).item(0).getTextContent());

                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName(Surname).getLength() > 0 )
                        enrollmentStatus.setLastName(eElement.getElementsByTagName(Surname).item(0).getTextContent());
```

etc..................

Expected result was Text value from Membership Status only . If Membership Status was Not available, return null .

Comment: What's your program language?

Comment: @Borja . Android Java.